# Bootstrap form not calling JS function on submit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which consists of a form whose on submit calls a javascript function.

```
<div class="form" role="form" onsubmit="createresult()">
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        $subject = $_GET["sub"];
        $array = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from questions where subject='$subject'");
        $j =1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($array))
        {
            echo "
            <div class=\"form-group\"><h5>$row[question]</h5>";
                for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
                {
                    $opt1 = "option".$i;
                    $opt = $row[$opt1];
                    $name = "question" ."$j";
                    echo "
                <label class=\"radio-inline\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name=$name required>$opt</label>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
            $j++;
        }
        ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The PHP script is working fine but this form is not calling the JavaScript function `createresult()`.

Comment: why not use a <form> tag ?

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit

The submit event happens when a user clicks a submit button inside a `<form>` tag. Right now you use a `<div>` tag.

If you would like to use the `<div>` tag, instead of using `onsubmit`, use `onclick` on the submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" onclick="createresult()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<div class="form" role="form" onsubmit="createresult()">
// your code
</div>
```

To

```
<form onsubmit="createresult()">
// your code
</form>
```